# Popup notifiers in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, notifications

I've been working on a project that will need a notifier in the system tray (sorry, "System Notification Area"). It will be a simple app that just generates popup notifications when it receives a message via a Zeromq socket.

I am not having any luck finding anything other than .NET resources and examples. Does anyone have a sample in C/C++?

Comment: Is there a reason to do it in C++?

Comment: I'm not allowed to do .net and most of our developers don't understand C++ so I'm stuck with C with little bits of C++. Sad, yes I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start with this section of MSDN: [Notifications and the Notification Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Then I'd check the [NotificationIcon Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940367(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 2):

What framework are you using? There should probably be several implementations for MFC, but there might different implementation for WTL and other frameworks. If you want to use the Windows API with no object orientation - well, you won't need any wrapper library then, but you can look at these libraries for example.

Here's one that has MFC and non-MFC version from CodeProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/systemtray.aspx

What you want here is probably ShowBalloon() function, which shows a balloon notification, but I'm pretty sure you must create a tray icon for that (can't have a notification balloon without having a tray icon).

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. This is a pretty simple app so I'm trying to avoid MFC if I can.